# Executing shell command in python: String error

Tags: python, cmd, windows-shell

I want to execute a batch file and a command on the windows shell cmd.exe per Python. Its this command:

`$cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 & msbuild ALL_BUILD.vcxproj"`

When I enter this line manually on the command prompt, it works. It starts a new shell, executes batch file `vcvarsall.bat` (with parameter x86) and then executes msbuild ALL_BUILD.vcxproj inside the shell. The path is quoted since it contains spaces.

Now if I try to execute this command in python with this command:

`subprocess.call(["cmd.exe", "/k", '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/vcvarsall.bat" x86 & msbuild ALL_BUILD.vcxproj'])`

I always get this error on the console:

> The command "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/vcvarsall.bat\"" could not be found.

Why does the command start with "\"C: instead of my entered "C: ?? Anyone has an idea how I could fix this?

Comment: try to use dos8.3 format of the path

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 '"C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 & msbuild ALL_BUILD.vcxproj'
```

You can't use inside "" - " (it will be escaped)

Comment: I already used single quotes as outer delimiters. I can't see any difference between your suggestion and my 3rd parameter

Comment: Did you try to set as extra parametr to call method `shell = True`?

Answer (score 0):

the `"x x"` on command line is equivalent to a `'x x'` in subprocess.call.
eventually you can leave some of the `"` out.

however.. did you try `os.system`?

```
import os

os.system('cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC vcvarsall.bat" x86 & msbuild ALL_BUILD.vcxproj"')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following from a Windows command-line  reference I have seems relevant:

> * Using multiple commands
>
> You can use multiple commands separated by the command separator **&&** for 
>   string, but you must enclose them in quotation marks (for example, 
>   "command&&command&&command").
>
> * Processing quotation marks
>
> If you specify /c or /k, cmd processes the remainder of string and **quotation marks 
>     are preserved only if all of the following conditions are met**:
>
> ```
> o   You do not use /s. 
> o   You use exactly one set of quotation marks. 
> o   You do not use any special characters within the quotation marks (for 
>     example: &<>( ) @ ^ |). 
> o   You use one or more white-space characters within the quotation marks. 
> o   The string within quotation marks is the name of an executable file. 
>     If the previous conditions are not met, string is processed by examining the first 
>     character to verify whether or not it is an opening quotation mark. If the first 
>     character is an opening quotation mark, it is stripped along with the closing 
>     quotation mark. Any text following the closing quotation marks is preserved.
> ```